# scrolltop with animate not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate while scrolling but no luck with my code...

I have this jquery

```
$(window).scrollTop(200);
```

Now wanted to give animation effect

So tried these but not working:

```
1. $(window).animate({scrollTop:200},1000);
2. $('body').animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);
```

I have applied this in a click function like this:

```
$('.goto').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(485); // its working
});
```

And now I want to give effect of animate but not working...

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fXx6c/1)?

Comment: How it's not working? Click _run_ and you'll se the _animation_.

Comment: nope! in my site.....

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Note on your update: you can't have `animate` on `$(window)`. Use `$('html,body')` instead. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXx6c/2/)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to use `$('html,body')` instead of `$(window)` because `window` does not have a scrollTop property.

```js
$('#scroll-bottom').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 2000
  }, 2000); // for all browsers
  
  // $('html').animate({scrollTop: 2000}, 2000); // works in Firefox and Chrome
  // $('body').animate({scrollTop: 2000}, 2000); // works in Safari
})
```

```css
#top {
  margin-bottom: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top">
  <button id="scroll-bottom">scroll</button>
</div>
<div>bottom</div>
```

Comment: Yes, in _chrome_ and _safari_ works for `$('html,body')` and `$(body)`, but in _firefox_ works for `$('html,body')` and `$(html)`. Obviously the `scrolltop` has some browser compatibility issues. However, use `$('html,body')`, that seems to work for both.

Comment: Anyone know of a solution for mobile devices as well?

Comment: What if you're in a modal/dialog box and you want to scroll to a specific part withing that section?

Nvm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072895/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-within-a-modal-using-jquery

Comment: that's weird I'm using Chrome v67.0.3396.99 and $('body') is not working... I have to use $('html, body')

Comment: You saved me, I did `$('html')` and my client complained it is not working on safari. `$('html, body')` works great.

Answer (score 50):

if you have html and body style height:100%; its not working
use

```
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks! The scroll top function wasnt working unless I did this.

Comment: Awesome! this works perfect. Stumbled upon this, thought very late, but found my solution. Bravo!

Comment: Wow that's strange... Had `height:100%` and that was causing all sorts of weird scrolling issues, especially on mobile...

Comment: Let me guess, many of us used to have `height: 100%` because of sticky footer technique :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I was playing with my js codes. But you solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you, couldn't get it working until I added this.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well and realised that the problem was within the CSS.

In my case, I needed to remove the overflow-x: hidden; from the HTML tag.

Remove:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Then, it worked.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add pixel

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: "300px" }, 1000);
```

Comment: changed window to 'body'

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4etct/102/)**

```
<html>
function scrollmetop(dest){
    var stop = $(dest).offset().top;
    var delay = 1000;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: stop}, delay);
    return false;
}

scrollmetop('#test');
<body>
    <div style="margin: 100px 100px 1000px 100px">
       <div id="test" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid black;">target object</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular and was trying to scroll down to an item that had been added in an ng-repeat. I put this code inside a `$timeout` (with zero time, just to make it happen after the elements displayed) and this was sufficient for the new item to have an `offset().top`...

...but I think there was just way too much going on adding dozens of new elements, so it didn't have the processing power to scroll-animate. When I set the timeout time to 1 second, it worked (though it actually took 7 seconds before the timeout got called).

I concluded that animated, smooth scrolling won't really be tractable here, and instead I'm just using

```
document.body.scrollTop = entry.offset().top
```