# $.animate works only in Chrome but not in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script is not working in Mozilla

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: $("body").find(".Pickup").offset().top - 200 }, 'slow');
```

What i have to do?

Comment: try $('html, body').animate(...);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrolltop with animate not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779708/scrolltop-with-animate-not-working)

Comment: It's worth trying to recreate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net so we can get a better look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox places the overflow at the html level, unless specifically styled to behave differently.

To get it to work in Firefox, use

```
$('body,html').animate( ... );
```